# How to slice a string in javascript that contain base64 encoded images and show the first image

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Below is my vue component which receives an object, 'feed' as prop
By default it shows only first 200 characters until user clicks 'read more' button

```
  <div class="answer">
      <div v-if="showLess">
        <div v-html="feed.answer.slice(0, 200) + '...'"></div>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <div v-html="feed.answer"></div>
      </div>
      <button
        class="button"
        @click="showLess = !showLess"
      >
        read more
      </button>
    </div>
```

The problem is feed.answer output string which contains raw html like this one

```
<p><em>rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or</em><p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/..." draggable="true" data-bukket-ext-bukket-draggable="true"></p>
```

How can I truncate above string and at the same time show only the first image from it (Which is embedded inside as base64.
Sorry my English is horrible..

Comment: what makes you think there's more than one image?

Comment: There can be more than one ,but i need to the first one only and truncate the rest